# Content-Security-Policy- scripts from localhost path

Tags: html, reactjs, content-security-policy

I am developing a website in React and I want to add `http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` to my `index.html` file. My current code includes this:

```
script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/
  https://maps.googleapis.com/
  'unsafe-inline';
```

But I get an error:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js' 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy 
directive: "script-src 'self' ...
```

The same for this script `'https://localhost:3000/node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.js'`.

When I add `https://localhost:3000/` to `script-src` list it gives me diffrent error:

```
GET https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js 0 ()
```